# Deno: Callback on exit

Tags: deno

How do you add a callback for the program exiting?

Implementation in nodejs:

```js
process.on('exit', function (){
    console.log('Goodbye!');
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `unload`

```
// window. also work outside workers
globalThis.addEventListener("unload", () => {
   console.log('goodbye!');
});

setTimeout(() => console.log('before goodbye'), 1000);
```

It'll be triggered when calling `Deno.exit()` as well. You can check more about [Program Lifecycle here](https://deno.land/manual/runtime/program_lifecycle).